# Angular is not working on the routed HTML page

Tags: angularjs

One of my HTML pages is like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-route.js"></script>
        <script>
            var module = angular.module("sampleApp", ['ngRoute']);

            module.config(['$routeProvider',
            function($routeProvider) {
                $routeProvider.
                    when('/route1', {
                        templateUrl: "test.html"
                    }).
                    otherwise({
                        redirectTo: '/'
                    });
            }]);
        </script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="sampleApp">
        <a href="#/route1" role="button">Route</a>
        <div ng-app="myApp" ng-view></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to navigate from this page to **test.html** through angular routing. **test.html** is as follows

```
<script>
    var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
    app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
        $scope.my = 10;
        ab = function() {
            alert($scope.my);
        }
    });
</script>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<div ng-app="myApp" data-ng-controller="myCtrl">
    {{10+20}}
    {{my}}
    <button onclick="ab()">click</button>
</div>
```

But angular is not working in **test.html**, i.e., {{10+20}} and {{my}} is displayed as it is. when I run **test.html** separately, then angular is working well. But when routed from the first html page it is not working.

Please help me out. Thanks.

Comment: No `ng-app` on the `div`.  You already have it on `body`.

Comment: Please add relatuve test.html part

Comment: Change the ng-app to div rather than body or remove the ng-app from test.html

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_routing  
I think this will help you.

Comment: Even after removing ng-app from div of main page its not working. If the second file is executed separately it is working well.

Comment: you seem to be missing a key concept of how angular routing is designed.  Angular is a Single Page Application (SPA).  The angular routing is designed to take the contents of templates and insert them into the `div` where `ng-view` is located.  these templates **ARE NOT** full pages, they are page sections.  Angular does not reload a different full page running angular on it's own;  if you ***really*** want that, then just use a normal `a` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-route.js"></script>
        <script>
            var module = angular.module("sampleApp", ['ngRoute']);

            module.config(['$routeProvider',
            function($routeProvider) {
                $routeProvider.
                    when('/route1', {
                        controller: 'myCtrl',
                        templateUrl: 'test.html'
                    }).
                    otherwise({
                        redirectTo: '/'
                    });
            }]);
          
          module.controller("MainController", function($scope) {
        
    });
          
    module.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
        $scope.my = 10;
        ab = function() {
            alert($scope.my);
        }
    });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="sampleApp">
      <div ng-controller="MainController"> 
           <a href="#/route1" role="button">Route</a> 
            <ng-view>

            </ng-view> 
        </div> 
    </body>
</html>
```

**And in your test.html, put this only :**

```
<div>
    {{10+20}}
        {{my}}
        <button onclick="ab()">click</button>
</div>
```

This all are in a working condition, i have test it in my local.
**You have to just make test.html file then all code snippet will works fine**