# ng-view doesn't show in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i want to make route with angularjs. but when i run my app, ng-view doesnt show anything. i'm new in angularjs.

index :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>CRUD</title>
</head>
<body ng-App="myAPP">
  <a href='#/'/>List</a>
  <a href='#/addData'/>Add Data</a>

  <div>
    <div ng-view></div>
  </div>

  <script src="js/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="js/angular-route.js"></script>
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  <script src="controller/controller.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

app.js :

```
var app=angular.module('myAPP',['ngRoute']);
```

route.js :

```
app.config(['$routeProvider',function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider.when('/',{
        templateURL : 'crud/pages/list.html',
        controller : 'controller'
    })
    .when('/addData',{
        templateURL : 'crud/pages/coba.html',
        controller : 'controller'
    })
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo : '/'
    })
}])
```

Comment: I have already given one answer,  Please refer this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40038399/angular-is-not-working-on-the-routed-html-page/40040614#40040614

Comment: your default route(/) loads list.html page. show your list.html page

Comment: have u declared controllers or not?

Answer (score 1):

You have not closed the `js/angular-route.js` tag

```
  <script src="js/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="js/angular-route.js"></script>
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
```

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/yllShhhuH1wimgSCqrF7?p=preview)**

Comment: just fix the templateURL, it will work, and yes the script tag is missing the trailing slash.  that should be corrected for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

You have written templateURL instead of written templateUrl. Other than that everything is fine.

And Please close the brackets `<script></script>`

templateURL --> templateUrl

Comment: i've close the brackets and change templateURL to templateUrl but it's still  cant show

Comment: did you define the controller function and are the templates paths correct and file present?

This works - http://plnkr.co/edit/RjXujNvD6hCTPudRwYIW?p=preview

Comment: Please check this link: [DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/mPR1qCT0jt2kQEFjt1ON?p=preview)

Comment: Its better you use angular-ui-router rather than angular-router. Angular UI-router has lot of components than angular-router. Please revisit the link: [DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/mPR1qCT0jt2kQEFjt1ON?p=preview)

Comment: Check this one, same as your demo : [DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/Ozz0puUqKt5zFrHc6Cxe?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

You should probably add all your script tag inside your head tag that would make it work and close the script tag too.

Answer (score 0):

check here for source code, cool to understand

https://github.com/umakantmane/single-page-app